# Highcharts treegraph chart type dataLabels are now shown for leaf nodes having a level greater or equal to 10

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

i encountered a problem related to dataLabels display for treegraph Highcharts chart,at first, leaf nodes having a level greater or equal than 10 was hidden (seems to be outside of the plot area and only arcs was shown see [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29s1m.png)) even though i increased the container width, to solve this, i just added a big right margin to the chart to be able to visualize those nodes, but then , there was no dataLabel inside those nodes/markers (see [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fp9rR.png)).

Can anyone help with this please?

I tried increasing the chart container width but always the chart seems to be zooming on and always got hidden leafs nodes , i tried to add marginRight to the chart , then i 'am able to visualize the leaf nodes but node data label was displayed inside them